# Iphone 5 can not restore!

Tags: iphone, itunes, recovery

Hello I have an Iphone 5 GSM it was jailbroken, i tried to do a manual update with the phone itself. Since then the devise is stuck on the apple logo and the loading bar is not moving. I tried to restore it with Itunes but it is not working, it says waiting for the Iphone but Iphone stays on the apple logo. Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried putting your iPhone in recovery mode? http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201263 or https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5269891

Comment: I did, itunes says extracting, then waiting for the iphone and nothing happens, the phone comes back to recovery mode. and why Itunes is not recognizing the DFU mode?